# React Native custom fonts working on IOS but not on Android

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

I've added the Google Font Fira Sans fonts (Italic, Bold, Regular), following the `react-native link` procedure.

I can see the fonts have been copied to `src/main/assets/fonts`, likewise in `Resources` folder for IOS

The fonts work fine on IOS but on android only Bold works but the Italic or Regular or any other font it doesnt work.

I have tried to set the `fontFamily` to the name property of the font but still no change

This is how I set my font variable

```
export const Fonts = {
    //Working on IOS but not on Android
    //I have tried `FiraSans-Italic` `Fira Sans Italic` and nothing works
    FiraSansItalic: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "FiraSans-Italic" : 'Fira Sans Italic',

    //Bold works fine for both platforms
    FiraSansBold: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "FiraSans-Bold" : "FiraSans-Bold"
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You need to refer the full font file name on Android, where on iOS you refer to font family name. For instance: `const FiraSans = (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'Fira Sans' : 'FiraSans.ttf';` (this is a comment provided without seeing the actual code).

Comment: @zvona thank you for your reply. I do have it exactly how you posted `(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "FiraSans-Italic" : 'FiraSans-Italic.ttf` , I did try to put the file extension like you have it but still no luck

Comment: This is how the full name when I check the font with Font book `Fira Sans Italic`, but even if I name the fontFamily like that it doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

For someone who got the same problem make sure you're not applying any of these (`fontWeight` or `fontStyle`) style to your textStyle if you do so it will drop your custom font style from your text.

Answer (score 1):

Check the filename for Android, android need to refer to the file name rather than font family name. Also make sure to set a `key` to your text/textInput component to make the customized font render properly after changing to a new font. (Android may still render old font if you don't do so)